# Change self.view's class type

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a app out for testing right now that's almost completely done - just a few bug fixes left. Unfortunately, the customer decided that they'd like the entire main page of the app to be inside of a scroll view (so that there's more room for the table at the bottom). I already have everything set up and I don't really want to move everything and change references. Is there an easy way to change the class of the main view to a scroll view? I've already tried changing the class in IB and setting the class type in the `init` method. If there isn't I'll probably just throw the top section of the view into a nib file and load it as a custom cell.

**-EDIT-** I ended up changing the class type in IB and then doing

```
[(UIScrollView *) self.view setScrollEnabled:YES];
[(UIScrollView *) self.view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0,2000)];
```

in `viewDidLoad`. Thanks for the help, wish I could accept all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are referring to `[self view]`, I am going to assume you mean in a view controller. The view of a view controller can be any view that derives from UIView. Thus a scrollview is completely acceptable.

```
I don't really want to move everything and change references.
```

what would you have to move? why would you have to change references? Only thing you should need to do is add a scroll view to your view controller, set the view controllers view to it, and add the current view as a subview to the new scroll view. No references need to be changed, nothing has to be moved.

Comment: The reason I don't want to do this is because this is a massive and somewhat poorly set-up project - mostly because of continuous design changes similar to this. I don't want to make the scrollview the top-level view (above the original view) because a lot of other classes reference the main view controller's view hierarchy. That's why I'm looking for a way to change the class of the top-level controller and retain my current hierarchy.

Comment: you can change your top view to a uiscrollview without problems. From what you have said, it sounds like you have lines like `[[viewcontroller views] objectAtIndex:0]`, if that is the case, my Zeus have mercy on your soul.

Comment: I changed it, but it doesn't scroll so I'm somewhat doubtful that it's actually a scrollview. I don't have `[[viewcontroller views] objectAtIndex:0]` but I do have things like `viewcontroller.view.tableview` and `self.view.textfield`. So if I added a scrollview I'd have to add a reference to the internal view and do `viewcontroller.view.something.tableview`. Because my project is ~8 billion LOC I don't want to have to look for all these references.

Comment: Did you set the content size? A scrollview doesn't know to scroll unless its content size is different from its frame. If you really want to check to make sure it is a scroll view, you can log `NSStringFromClass([[self view] class])`

Comment: I did log the class's description and it came up as `UIScrollView`. I casted `self.view` and set `scrollEnabled` and `bounces` to true, but I guess I'll check if changing the content size works.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [loadView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method in documentation of view controller.

Here is a simple (untested!) example

```
- (void)loadView {
   UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init] autorelease];

   //Set the properties of scrollview appropriately....

   self.view = scrollView;
 }
```

Now the root view of your view controller will be a scroll view.

*Note* 
- As the documentation states, do not do this if you are using interface builder to initialize your views/view controller. I could not tell from your description if this was the case or not. If it is, you should be able to change the view type in interface builder.

Comment: I am using IB. If I change the view type in IB, it still doesn't scroll.

Comment: I found this post https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1996598?start=0&tstart=0 didn't read it all but may help, check it out

Comment: Also, make sure you are setting the contentSize larger than the screen to make the scrollView scrollable

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `contentSize` property of your scrollview.

Since you are using IB, the easiest way to do this is to put all your UI elements into a view and add this single view to your scroll view. In the `viewDidLoad` method, set the content size of the scrollview to be the same size as the view that contains all your UI.

As an aside, there are much easier ways to reference views than walking down the view hierarchy, as you seem to be doing. `viewcontroller.view.something.tableview`. Add a connection to the tableview from your view controller in IB and it doesn't matter where that tableview is in the view hierarchy. You'll always be able to reach it from `viewcontroller.tableview`, no matter how you rearrange your nibs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a pointer with proper type. Example for Google Maps: let's say you changed you base view's class to `GMSMapView`.

**MapViewController.h**

```
@property GMSMapView *mapView;
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.mapView = (GMSMapView*)self.view;
    // ... etc.
}
```